# Laravel: how to save/update multiple records.

Tags: php, laravel

Someone explain to me how `saveMany()` works. I want to update multiple existing records.

e.g. A plate container has many plates in it. When the user selects plates from drop down I want to assign the selected plates into the container.

How I might achieve this. This code does not work.

```
   $plateContainer = PlateContainer::find($plateContID);

     $arr = [
        'plate_id' => 1,
        'plate_id' => 2,
      ];
     $plateContainer->plates()->saveMany($arr);
```

Maybe I just don't understand it very well.

Comment: You appear to be using it correctly, but there is very little information here to go off of. What happens when it 'does not work'? Any error? What do your models look like? Have you properly configured the relation and your database tables?

Comment: @MikelBitson I do have my models good I am already using it for other purposes. But for this case is not working. ` Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, null given`   I have used this code now. `      $plateContainer = \App\Models\PlateContainer::find(2);

      $arr = [
        \App\Models\Plate::find(1),
        \App\Models\Plate::find(2),
       ];
      $plateContainer->plates()->saveMany($arr);`

Comment: Are you sure that the properties you're trying to save are `fillable`? saveMany sounds like a mass-assignment :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `save()` method, you need to pass a full Eloquent model, unlike `create()` method which might accept an array of parameters.

As I understand, there is no createMany method. So in your case, you need to do it like that:

```
$plateContainer = PlateContainer::find($plateContID);
$plateContainer->plates()->saveMany([
  new \App\Plate(['title'=>'Plate1']);
  new \App\Plate(['title'=>'Plate2']);
]);
```

Comment: A plate container has many plates in it. I need to update the plate container with id's of the plates. I thought I might use `save()` to do so.

Comment: You want to update the container itself, or the plates inside the container. Or add more plates to container?

Comment: I want to update the container itself with the plates the user selected.

Comment: In your example, you were trying to add new plates to the container.

Comment: I know.. :( I am sorry. I just can't understand this very well.

Comment: No it's OK, so there is a table with Plates, and another with PlateContainers, and you want the user to have a new PlateContainer, and select plates from the existing Plates. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95941/discussion-between-user3641381-and-mina-youssef).